# Accelerated Ball leaving screen (Processing 2.1)

Tags: processing

It is supposed to be a balloon going up, stoping when the window ends. I cannot understand why my ball eventually disappears... Somebody help me.... When I try to tune the gravity parameter or the accelereation one, it either starts moving crazy fast (and dissapears), or real slow (eventually dissapears too). I have the checkEdges(), method defined so that this does not happen. Obviously something is not right

```java
Mover mover;
 void setup(){

    size(300,600);
    background(255);
    mover = new Mover();
 }

  void draw(){

    background(255,50);

    mover.applyForceWind();
    mover.applyForceGravity();
    mover.update();
    mover.display();
    mover.checkEdges();
 }


class Mover {

  PVector location;
  PVector velocity;
  PVector acceleration;
  PVector gravity;
  PVector wind;


    Mover(){

      location = new PVector(width/2,height*0.9);
      velocity = new PVector(0,0);
      acceleration = new PVector(0,-1);

      }

   void applyForceWind(){
     PVector wind = new PVector(0.001,0);
    acceleration.add(wind);
   }

    void applyForceGravity(){
      PVector gravity = new PVector(0,0.1);
      acceleration.add(gravity);
    }


   void update(){
     velocity.add(acceleration);
     location.add(velocity);
     acceleration.mult(0);
   }

   void display(){
     stroke(0);
     fill(155);
     ellipse(location.x,location.y,30,30);
   }

   void checkEdges(){
     if ( location.x > width || location.x < 0){ velocity.x *= (-1);}
     if ( location.y > height || location.y < 0){ velocity.y *=(-1);}
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had an extra close curly brace in your code, just FYI. The problem with the ball eventually getting "stuck" on the floor and disappearing is due to your `checkEdges()` code, as you suspected. To shed some light on the issue, try this code:

```java
   void checkEdges(){
     if ( location.x > width || location.x < 0){ velocity.x *= (-1);}
     if ( location.y > height || location.y < 0){ 
       velocity.y *=(-1);
       println("velocity: " + velocity.y + "; position: " + location.y);
     }
   }
```

And it will give something like this:

```
...
velocity: -2.3999999; position: 602.1
velocity: -2.3; position: 602.1
velocity: -2.2; position: 602.1
velocity: -2.1000001; position: 602.1
velocity: 2.0000002; position: 600.1
velocity: -2.1000001; position: 602.19995
velocity: 2.0000002; position: 600.19995
velocity: -2.1000001; position: 602.2999
velocity: 2.0000002; position: 600.2999
...
```

As you can see, the y-velocity at each successive "bounce" is slightly lower than the one before it, meaning that your system is bleeding energy. In particular, when the velocity becomes too low to get it back above the bottom of the screen (it goes below 2.1, which how far it has to go to get back up), it starts behaving erratically. Imagine it goes for a while, and then the next time it has to bounce, it only has a y velocity of -2. It's at y=602.1 > 600, so multiply y velocity by negative one. On the next iteration, it moves up 2 units, so y is now 600.1, but that is *still off the screen* so it inverts the velocity again! Here's a (crude) picture to illustrate the idea:

[image: Bouncing Problem]

The red lines represent the iteration after the velocity was reversed. The length of each red line decreases as time goes on (the ball doesn't bounce quite as high), and eventually it doesn't actually get back above the barrier! At this point, it's still below the bottom of the screen, and so the inversion test still passes, so it turns the positive velocity negative, *while it's still below the bottom of the screen*.

There are a few ways to fix this:

- Prevent the ball from losing energy as time goes on. This can be tricky to do. Here's a clue: if you swap the order of these two lines in your `update()` function, the ball will gain energy as time goes on! An interesting result.

  `location.add(velocity);`

  `velocity.add(acceleration);`
- It doesn't make sense to allow the ball to go below the edge of the window anyway, so if it is there, then force it back up to the edge, ie insert this into your `checkEdges()` method:

  `location.y = height;`

When I use the second bullet, I get a constant bounce response and no loss of speed as time goes on:

```
velocity: -3.5999987; position: 600.0
velocity: -3.5999987; position: 600.0
velocity: -3.5999987; position: 600.0
velocity: -3.5999987; position: 600.0
velocity: -3.5999987; position: 600.0
velocity: -3.5999987; position: 600.0
```

Also, a side note: there is no need to create new `wind` and `gravity` PVectors each time you call the methods. In fact, you even declared them as class variables anyways! Set their values in the constructor and then you can use them in your other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, acceleration is constant, but you're adding to it every iteration....

Comment: He zeros the acceleration on every call to `update()`.